# MySQL join is scanning the table rather than using the index

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have following tables:

SHOW CREATE TABLE access_token_status;

```
CREATE TABLE `access_token_status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `idx_access_token_status_status_lookup_2` (`status`,`id`),
  KEY `idx_access_token_status_status_lookup_1` (`id`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

and

SHOW CREATE TABLE user;

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `short_lived_access_token_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_user_status_lookup_1` (`id`,`short_lived_access_token_status_id`),
  KEY `idx_user_status_lookup_2` (`short_lived_access_token_status_id`,`id`),
  KEY `ix_user_short_lived_access_token_status_id` (`short_lived_access_token_status_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`short_lived_access_token_status_id`) REFERENCES `access_token_status` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

and

SHOW CREATE TABLE account;

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `track` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `estimated_time_to_regain_access` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `media_list_fetched_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_account_next_fetch_lookup` (`user_id`,`estimated_time_to_regain_access`,`track`,`media_list_fetched_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_chk_1` CHECK ((`track` in (0,1)))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

When I try to explain the following query

```
explain select a.*
        from account a
        inner join user u
        on a.user_id = u.id
        inner  join access_token_status as s
        on u.short_lived_access_token_status_id = s.id and s.status = 'valid'
        where
            u.short_lived_access_token_status_id = 3
            and a.estimated_time_to_regain_access = 0
            and a.track = true
            and a.media_list_fetched_at > '2020-05-30 12:31:01'
        limit 1
        for update of a SKIP LOCKED
```

I get this output:

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 's', NULL, 'const', 'PRIMARY,status,idx_access_token_status_status_lookup_2,idx_access_token_status_status_lookup_1', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'const', '1', '100.00', NULL
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'a', NULL, 'index', 'idx_account_next_fetch_lookup', 'idx_account_next_fetch_lookup', '80', NULL, '2', '50.00', 'Using where; Using index'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'u', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY,idx_user_status_lookup_1,idx_user_status_lookup_2,ix_user_short_lived_access_token_status_id', 'PRIMARY', '70', 'media_meta.a.user_id', '1', '100.00', 'Using where'
```

It seems like indexes are not being used for some tables. This is an issue for my case as the scanned rows get locked and other queries will skip them (due to SKIP LOCKED which is required to make sure queries are not blocked on each other)

I'm not sure what index I'm missing or if I need to change something in the query

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: I'd try changing the order of the index so that user_id came at the end

Comment: Also, I can think of no good reason for an id not to be an an integer

Comment: The order doesn't matter in my use case, I didn't provide such details to avoid distractions. But would that affect the execution plan? You are right about index, again it's business logic that might be out of scope of the question, unless you think that is changing execution plan (I did try integer id, but plan didn't change) I did try adding a new index with user_id at the end, and that did work, thanks

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: If you consider this solved, feel free to answer the question and accept your own answer, or othewise delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you use "u.short_lived_access_token_status_id = 3", so the join with "s" looks either impossible (if s.status for s.id = 3 is NOT "valid") or superfluous (if it is). Unless you are fetching some other columns from s.

Let us now see where "u" is used:

```
on a.user_id = u.id
...
    on u.short_lived_access_token_status_id = ...
```

So you are using a main selection criterion based on u.short_lived_access_token_status_id = 3, and from this you need to get u.id. So your `idx_user_status_lookup_2` ought to work as a covering index.

Why doesn't it? Possibly because the table is so small that it doesn't matter very much, or because the join with S is interfering with the optimizer (you'll note that the table u is evaluated third).

If at all possible, try removing the join with s and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be "over-normalization".

I don't see any advantage in moving `status` out of the table into another table.  Doing so complicates optimization and does not save much, if any, space.

In fact, you could use an `ENUM('invalid', 'valid', ...) NOT NULL`, which would take 1 byte instead of 4 bytes for `INT`.

In InnoDB, when you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, you have a BTree ordered by `id`.  Hence, any secondary index *starting* with `id` is redundant.  Note also that a `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition, `UNIQUE`.

```
    where
        u.short_lived_access_token_status_id = 3
        and a.estimated_time_to_regain_access = 0
        and a.track = true
        and a.media_list_fetched_at > '2020-05-30 12:31:01'
```

would like to use either

```
INDEX(short_lived_access_token_status_id, ...)
```

but that seems very unlikely due to low cardinality, or

```
INDEX(estimated_time_to_regain_access, track,   -- in either order
      media_list_fetched_at)    -- last, since it is a 'range'
```

Even better would be this "covering" index:

```
INDEX(estimated_time_to_regain_access, track,
      media_list_fetched_at, user_id)
```